# Module getServiceConfig not injecting TableGateway into repository

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I can't seem to get my table gateway to inject into my repository(service)...

I have the following:

**Module.php:**

```
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Album\Model\Concrete\AlbumRepository' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                    $table = new AlbumRepository($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                    return new TableGateway('albums', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                }
            )
        );
    }
```

and here is my **module.config.php:**

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Album\Model\Abstracts\IAlbumRepository' => 'Album\Model\Concrete\AlbumRepository'
         ),
     ),

     'controllers' => array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Model\Factories\AlbumControllerFactory',
         ),
     ),
```

the error is:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Album\Model\Concrete\AlbumRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendFrameworkTest\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php on line 1035 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendFrameworkTest\module\Album\src\Album\Model\Concrete\AlbumRepository.php on line 11
```

**Note:**

the delegate functions on the factories array are just not getting called, i'm doing somethign silly but i can't tell what.

I'm also doing dependancy injection, i'm guessing this is where it's going wrong as the factory is creating the repository object without the injection:

```
class AlbumControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create service
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        // Need to do something here?
        $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $postService        = $realServiceLocator->get('Album\Model\Abstracts\IAlbumRepository');

        return new AlbumController($postService);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined your repository as invokable, that means that service manager tries to create it by instantiating directly without any params.

change it to alias

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
         'aliases' => array(
             'Album\Model\Abstracts\IAlbumRepository' => 'Album\Model\Concrete\AlbumRepository'
         ),
     ),
);
```